# Limiting Processor Core Count Usage

Tags: elixir

How do I limit processor core count usage in an elixir application?

I know I can use `+S` command in erlang, but I'm not sure how to use that command from elixir realm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For iex you can do:

```
iex --erl "+S 1" -S mix some_task
```

For running elixir you can do:

```
elixir --erl "+S 1" -S mix some_task
```